# how to make video size increases when site is visited. HTML java script possibly JQuery? Video animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a video pop up in the same window when I visit a site. By doing this I want to increase the height of the video from 0 to the specific height and then move the video slightly up from where its from. Is there a java script function or JQuery function that can allow this. Code would be great with comments but I am ok If there is a site that gives a walkthrough of how to do it. Thank you
Code I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Team Songs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
var t;
var x;
window.onload=function()
{
    x = 0;
    while(x < 300)
{
    t = setTimeout("nothing();",30000);
  x = x + 10;
}
}  
function nothing()
{
       var b = x + 'px';
   document.getElementById("mainvideo").height = b;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h2>Software Engineering</h2>
<h2>Team Songs</h2>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<iframe id="mainvideo" width="560" height="315"      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2SZGW-6AF3A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: yeah let me update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the jQuery .animate() method : http://api.jquery.com/animate/  or the slideDown method http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

For your specific case I think you should first make sure that the element containing the video is going to resize without destroying your page's layout. Then use

```
$("#container_div_id").slideDown(1000, function(){
    $("#container_div_id").css("position","relative");
    $("#container_div_id").css("bottom", "10px");
})
```

If you want it to slide up, then it would be more complicated as you would have to have the div fixed to the bottom or something and maybe changing its position property to relative might move it more than you wanted.

Comment: How would I be destroying the pages layout if I re size the element containing the video?

Comment: It depends, this will probably work without issues but if you have floated elements around or have a really static layout you may get unexpected results. Just try